# How to list all strings of length 12 in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm a novice programmer studying my own. I tried to make a program that lists all strings of length 12 such as its characters are from a-z. However, there seems to be a bug I could find. It outputs for example `The word is ).` Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and is there some easier way to do the program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    string l ("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm");
    string test ("");
    for(int i1 = 0;i1 < 26;++i1)
    for(int i2 = 0;i2 < 26;++i2)
    for(int i3 = 0;i3 < 26;++i3)
    for(int i4 = 0;i4 < 26;++i4)
    for(int i5 = 0;i5 < 26;++i5)
    for(int i6 = 0;i6 < 26;++i6)
    for(int i7 = 0;i7 < 26;++i7)
    for(int i8 = 0;i8 < 26;++i8)
    for(int i9 = 0;i9 < 26;++i9)
    for(int i10 = 0;i10 < 26;++i10)
    for(int i11 = 0;i11 < 26;++i11)
    for(int i12 = 0;i12 < 26;++i12)  {
        test = l[i1]+l[i2]+l[i3]+l[i4]+l[i5]+l[i6]+l[i7]+l[i8]+l[i9]+l[i10]+l[i11]+l[i12];
        cout << "The word is " << test << "." << endl;
        test = "";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just about as confusing as it could possibly be.

Comment: Any time you catch yourself repeating like that, think of making a function. In this case, a recursive function. As for what you're doing wrong, an expression such as `l[i1]` returns a character, which (due to legacy C support) is also considered an integer, not a length=1 string. So when you "add" them, you're adding the character codes and getting a new code.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Personally, I completely disagree. I can read and understand this code in about 10 seconds. It's certainly difficult to extend or make generic, but that doesn't mean that the code is confusing.

Comment: @BillLynch: So you think the sentence *I tried to make a program that lists all strings of length 12 such as its characters are from a-z* was well constructed? You don't think proper indentation makes code easier to read? You really think the concepts were well presented here?

Comment: ALL strings? Have you estimated how many strings you are going to print? Assuming you print a million strings per second you will need about 3 thousands years to complete the task.

Comment: Oops. I just saw a programming problem to find a 12 letter long word with given md5-hash and as someone was able to do it, I tried to brute force solution. Well, maybe the person who solved it used some other method or distributed computing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l[i1]+l[i2]` won't do what you expect. You're adding two expressions of type `char` so you'll get a result of type `int`.

An easy fix is:

```
test = std::string() + l[i1]+l[i2]+l[i3]+l[i4]+l[i5]+l[i6]+l[i7]+l[i8]+l[i9]+l[i10]+l[i11]+l[i12];
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, when you see a permutations problem like this you should think of how to write a recursive algorithm.

In this case, ask yourself what each step (level) looks like. Well, you're given the string up to that point, you need to iterate through the letters, and you need to call the next level down each time so it can continue the process.

Working that out into code, "given the string up to this point" means your recursive function is passed in the prefix string, and a number indicating where it is in the chain:

```
void print_all_strings(const std::string& prefix, unsigned remain) {
```

Iterating through the letters is something you've already got (use a `for` loop), but the way you're doing it is not great. Instead of typing all the characters into a string and iterating through those characters, you're better off realizing that you can iterate through characters in a `for` loop like you can iterate through numbers, since characters are numbers in C++ (and C). In other words, `'a' + 1 == 'b'` and so forth. So your loop becomes:

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
```

Finally, you need to handle the next level down. That means using the `prefix` and `remain` parameters to figure out what to do next. Well, there's one thing we know: if there are 0 letters left, then don't add a letter, but instead print the string and return!

```
if(remain == 0) {
    cout << "The word is " << prefix << "." << endl;
    return;
}
```

In other cases, we need to add a letter. That's where `std::string + char => std::string` comes in. (Note that `char + char => char`!)

```
print_all_strings(prefix + c, remain - 1);
```

Putting it all together:

```
void print_all_strings(const std::string& prefix, unsigned remain) {
    if(remain == 0) {
        cout << "The word is " << prefix << "." << endl;
        return;
    }
    for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        print_all_strings(prefix + c, remain - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_all_strings("", 12);
    return 0;
}
```

But then, as CiaPan explained, your computer will die before this program finishes.